# riot jsfiddle breaks when adding a tag function

Tags: jsfiddle, riot.js

This fiddle is broken.  Remove the oops function to fix it.  What do I do when I need the oops function?
https://jsfiddle.net/mvvapzub/1/

```
oops(e) {

}
```

Here is a fiddle that has a riot function (isFolder) and it's not broken.
https://jsfiddle.net/walkermatt/1vdo5pmf/1/

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by indenting everything inside the script tag

https://jsfiddle.net/mvvapzub/3/

```
/// this does NOT work
<script type="riot/tag">
<app>
    <table>
        ...
    </table>

    ...

    oops(e) {
        return true
    }

</app>
</script>
```

.

```
/// this works
<script type="riot/tag">
    <app>
        <table>
            ...
        </table>

        ...

        oops(e) {
            return true
        }

    </app>
</script>
```